# Программирование под iOS

Tags: xcode, ios

Привет. Давно хочется научиться программировать под iOS, но какую инструкцию не погляди, везде пишут, что без Mac OS не обойтись. Покупать - не богат. Виртуальные машины и хакинтош - не хочу заморачиваться, пока не узнаю ответ на вопрос. А вопрос такой: для начинающего действительно нужно что-то из выше написанного или можно обойтись пока что теорией? Или все же толку от теории не будет, если не подкреплять практикой?

Answer (score 1):

1. Виртуальная машина — да, выход.
2. Купите компьютер Mac б/у.
3. Можно готовый «Хакинтош» собрать на "bizon-pc" на свой страх и риск.
4. Теории будет маловато.

Comment: Bizon-PC? Эта штука была лет 5 назад «популярна», и даже тогда это была просто флешка с загрузчиком.  
Сейчас технологии установки Хакинтоша ушли далеко вперёд, и установить OS X можно на любом более-менее распространённом железе.

Comment: Кстати - да, много ума не надо, соберите сами хакинтош все в инете есть. нужно тока подобрать железо под DSL и все. Ну может где то kextы понадобятся.

Answer (score 0):

Да нужен мак, лучше подкреплять практикой. Но можно прокачивать навыки Objective-C. Компиляторы есть и под Windows.

Comment: Я сразу хочу предупредить топикстартера, что под Windows вы будете изучать **другой** Objective-C, чем тот, на котором пишутся программы под iOS. Там не только библиотеки (даже стандартные) разные, но и runtime отличается.